# Creating a txt file from strings in a column R

Tags: r, txt

I have this table

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | x | 1 | k1 |
| B | k | 2 | k2 |
| C | z | 3 | k3 |
| D | y | 4 | k4 |

I would like to print a txt file containing all the string in column A, divided by comma.
Output:
txt file --> A,B,C,D

```
df1 <- structure(list(ColumnA = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), ColumnB = c("x", 
"k", "z", "y"), ColumnC = 1:4, ColumnD = c("k1", "k2", "k3", 
"k4")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: I need to write just the elements in the first column, as in the example. So I need a text file containing this: A,B,C,D

Comment: @ZheyuanLi That should be an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use

```
cat(df1$ColumnA, sep = ",", file = "output.txt")
```